# Questions about the ThreadPool

Tags: c#, multithreading, threadpool

I have a few questions about the `ThreadPool`. Primarily, If I wanted to limit the number of threads in execution asynchronously, what would I change? Secondly, in [set maximum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool.setmaxthreads) and [set minimum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool.setminthreads) number of threads, what are the completion port threads?

Comment: No sufficient answers yet....

Answer (score 7):

Don't mess with the `ThreadPool` (i.e. limiting threads) - it isn't yours to mess with, and core parts of the system will want it. You risk starvation and deadlock.

Either use a custom thread-pool implementation, or use the inbuilt options in the TPL to run an operation on a constrained number of threads.

Comment: what about SetMaxThreads? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.setmaxthreads.aspx and SetMinThreads. What's the point in providing those methods if it is risky?

Comment: @0A0D you mean, with the warning "Use caution when changing the maximum number of threads in the thread pool. While your code might benefit, the changes might have an adverse effect on code libraries you use."

Comment: @0A0D my point is: in the scenario presented by the OP, it is a non-issue. If you need that level of control, don't use the `ThreadPool`. You might *wind them in a bit* with those methods, but for scaling issues not specific to any individual task. And even then I'd frankly let the system mange it internally.

Comment: Well I HAVE to use threadpool because I don't know how many threads I need to fire off. And I need to change the maximum number because I want one execution per processor (not knowing how many cores they have). So really I can't use the tpl library can I? And I cant use a custom threadpool either 0.o

Comment: @Joey G - whatever you do, *DON'T* set the thread-pool that tight! And yes, you *can* easily use a custom thread pool - just spin up as many workers as you have cores (`Environment.ProcessorCount`). Likewise TPL - just use `Environment.ProcessorCount` to set the value of `ParallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism`.

Comment: Well what do I do if I don't know the amount of threads I have to make. Like say the computer has 16 cores and I want to execute the same .exe 16 times in a row. I would use thread pool to queue the threads and set the max number of threads to 16. I mean how else could I do that?

Comment: @Joey if you are executing an exe, there is no point using *any* threads... just use `Process.Start` 16 times. Those exes are completely external, so the right way to do that is to either use `WaitForExit` (to "join") them back together, or listen for the `Exited` event.

Comment: @Joey but in the more *general* sense... well, to be honest I'm not sure it makes *sense* to discuss threading "in general" - it is so important that it needs specific scenarios.

Comment: No I do have to use threads because it is interacting with a GUI and will lock it up.